# XSLT: selecting first node and replacing text of it

Tags: xslt

I am learning xslt, so please excuse if below xml doesn't make sense. here is my sample xml.

```
<root>
<note>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>ABC</test1>
</to>

<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>content1</test1>
</to>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>ABC</test1>
</to>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>content1</test1>
</to>
</note>
<nodeabc>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>ABC</test1>
</to>

 </nodeabc>
 </root>
```

I am trying to change text of first node "test" when there is node "test1" with text=content1.

for example
out put should be.

```
<root>
<note>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>ABC</test1>
</to>

<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>REPLACED</test1>
</to>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>ABC</test1>
</to>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>content1</test1>
</to>
</note>
<nodeabc>
<to>
    <test>text</test>
    <test1>ABC</test1>
</to>

 </nodeabc>
 </root>
```

I tried few xslt but nothing seems to work. it replaces all the occurrence of text of node "test" where corresponding "test1" have value content1.

part of xslt

```
<xsl:template match="to/test[../test1='content1'][1]/text()">REPLACED
 </xsl:template >
```

please guide what can be solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current expression, is that it matching **test** elements that are the first child of the **to** element. In your case, you really want to matching the first **to** element.

Try this expression

```
 <xsl:template match="to[test1='content1'][1]/test/text()">REPLACED
 </xsl:template>
```